# Are all eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian Operator stationary waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I had a quick question regarding eigenfunctions, wave functions, and the TISE.

To put it frankly, are all eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator stationary waves? And thus, are wave functions resulting from the TISE stationary?

If the wave function for the TISE is of the form...
$$
\psi(x,t)=\phi(x)e^{-(iEt/\hbar)}
$$
wouldn't this be representative of a standing wave where $\phi(x)$ is oscillating with the phase factor, $e^{-(iEt/\hbar)}$?

I do apologize if my question sounds a bit "dumb", however, neither the internet nor my textbook have been that much of a help. Some sources say that all solutions of the TISE are stationary meanwhile others differ.

Moreover, if *not* all solutions of the TISE are stationary, then how does one go about finding which ones are and which aren't?

I'd appreciate any corrections of my work, advice, ideas, answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all solutions to the TISE are stationary. The TISE is the eigenvalue equation; it's said that energy eigenstates don't evolve in time. You could roughly, roughly think of this as related to a time-energy uncertainty principle: knowing the energy exactly makes the state stationary.

Of course the phase can change as you say, but if the result of a measurement gives us $|\psi|^2$, then the global phase didn't matter anyway; "global" here meaning that it's a factor overall on all of $\psi$ rather than on a term within $\psi$.

Also of note: These solutions are not, except in very special circumstances, the time-evolution of the wave function in general. That is given by the TDSE and is typically not a stationary state. I've encountered physicists who solved the TISE and were confused when it was pointed out that that didn't fully solve the evolution of the wave function.

Comment: hey! I had a small question that relates to your answer: In my intro to QM textbook, it mentions how for x>0 in the step potential (energy greater than potential), the wave function there is, and I quote, "a pure traveling wave traveling to the right". Yet, how can it be moving if it is a stationary state? (Since we explicitly said that the potential is not a function of time and we instead derived it from the TISE). Would it, instead, just be a standing plane wave of the form e^ikx with the same phase that you described in your answer above? Thanks again!

Comment: Good question. The standing waves $e^{ikx}$ are actually a weird example of a wave function and there is a lot to understand about them. You may observe that they are momentum eigenstates, namely $P|\psi \rangle = \hbar k |\psi \rangle $. The velocity operator being just p/m, these stationary states (at least when H=P^2/2m they are nonmoving) are actually states of definite velocity and momentum! How can that be?

Well, the uncertainty principle sheds some light here. Since these states have no uncertainty in momentum at all ($\sigma_p=0$) they must have an infinite spread in position. And,

Comment: in fact, for these states $|\psi(x)|^2=1$ for all $x$, which isn't even a probability density, but there is no legitimate normalizable probability density for which the density is equal at all points. Actually these states are an idealization and it's thought that they never *exactly* occur in nature, yet they are still important in the theory. Anyway the punchline is, if you already have equal probability of being everywhere, and you are moving with a constant velocity, then in the next moment you will *still* have equal probability of being everywhere. In that sense the states have definite

Comment: velocity yet have a stationary probability distribution in position.

Answer (score 1):

The search for solutions to the time-dependent SE starts with the ansatz $\Psi(x,t)=\psi_E(x)e^{-i E t}$ where $\psi(x)$ satisfies the TISE with energy $E$:
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi_E(x)+V(x)\psi(x)=E\psi_E(x)\, .
$$
The $\psi_E(x)$ have well-defined energy so if you have a problem where the system does not have a well defined energy, meaning $\Delta E\ne 0$, then the system will be described by a sum of $\psi_E(x)$’s for the various possible $E$’s of your system.

It’s actually a bit easier to see with the time-dependent version.
One you have the set of $\{\psi_E(x)\}$, you can build *any* solution to the time-*dependent* Schrodinger equation in the form of a superposition
$$
\Psi(x,t)=\sum_{k} c_k\psi_{E_k}(x)e^{-iE_kt/\hbar}
$$
so at $t=0$ this reduces to
$$
\Psi(x,0)=\sum_k c_k\psi_{E_k}(x) \tag{1}
$$
For such solutions the average energy at $t=0$ is
$$
\langle E\rangle =\sum_k \vert c_k\vert^2 E_k 
$$
and unless there is a single $k$ in the sum the variance $\Delta E^2\ne 0$, so Eq.(1) does not represent a state with definite energy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @ZeroTheHero ! Quick question: in terms of the summation equation that you said is the solution to the TDSE, does that mean that the sum of stationary states is NOT stationary?

Comment: @m_1265 correct.  A sum of solutions involving different energies will not be stationary.